# What is the difference between this->data, and directly just data?

Tags: object-oriented, c++

In C++ Is using

```
this->data
```

slower than

```
data
```

?

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if the compiler silently converted one to the other, so that they were both equivalent.  In any case, the performance difference between the two (if there is one) is almost certainly so small that it is something you should not worry about.

Comment: It is slower to type, and that's all.  The compiler converts the latter to the former.

Comment: Iff they are functionally identical, there should not be any difference, at least if the code is not interpreted. It's a QoI issue which is actually a non-issue.

Answer (score 4):

In most cases, there won't be a noticeable difference (unless you have the obvious case with method parameters named the same as member variables). But beware of templates!

```
template <typename T> struct Base {
    int i;
};

template <typename T> struct Derived : public Base<T> {
    int get_i() { return i; }
};
```

This will cause a compilation error, unless there is a global or somehow other accessible variable named `i`. Why? Because there could be a later specialization of `Base<T>` that does not contain a declaration for `i`. To fix the error (by telling the compiler it should delay the lookup of `i` until `Derived<T>` is instantiated), you would have to either use `this->i` or `Base<T>::i` (or bring it into scope with a using declaration).

For more information on this topic, search for "two phase name lookup".

Sources: [GCC online docs about name lookup](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Name-lookup.html)

Comment: This doesn't address speed at all, since one case simply does not compile.

Comment: Beware of templates, indeed! Templates are the one and only place where I do use `this`.

Answer (score 1):

No surprises. They are functionally identical.

In order for the compiler to locate the member, the compiler must use the hidden `this` parameter. Therefore there is no functional difference between accessing a member with or without using `this`.

The reason to use `this` is to disambiguate other names that may be in scope.

Answer (score 0):

If a class has a member variable named `data` and one of its (non-static) member functions also has a *local* variable (or parameter) named `data`, then `data` is the local variable and `this->data` is the member variable.

```
class Point
{
   double x, y;
// ...
};

// Constructor with parameters named the same as the member vars
Point::Point(double x, double y)
{
   this->x = x;
   this->y = y;
}
```

If not, then there is no difference: `data` and `this->data` refer to the same member variable.  The only reason to write the `this->` is to clarify that you mean a member variable instead of a local (and even this is unnecessary if you adopt a convention like prefixing member variables with `m_`).

Comment: Blech. I hate Hungarian notation in all its forms, and that would include `m_foo`. I'm not going to downvote, but blech. The solution to having a data member named `foo` and an argument or local variable named `foo` is the same as going to your doctor and complaining "Doctor! It hurts when I do this!" The solution: Don't do that then.